# Adding a foreign key constraint fill up my transaction log

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

When trying to add a foreign key constraint on an existing table in SQL Server 2000, I get an error message saying that the transaction log is full. What are the possible reasons why data is being added to the transaction log when a foreign key constraint is being created and what remedy can I apply to each of these reasons? Also, if multiple reasons exist, how can I diagnose which of those reasons are relevant to me?

The script causing the error is a simple one that follows this pattern:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName] ADD
CONSTRAINT [key_name] FOREIGN KEY
(
    [columnId]
) REFERENCES [dbo].[otherTableName] (
    columnId
)
GO
```

Comment: I'd have guessed that this is largely a metadata change and wouldn't require much logging (just checking the existing data validates and a logged addition to the system tables) Can you perform any logged operations against this database or is your transaction log 100% full?

Comment: I just ran `DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)` and the database is using 3% of the log and 40% of the Master's log space is being used. I hope that this is the right information that you asked about - my knowledge of how the SQL Server transaction log is very basic.

Comment: Yes that was what I was asking. I'm not sure why adding a FK would generate much logging activity either then.

Comment: something silly to check - make sure you don't have a drive space issue on the drive that has the log.  The error message you get indicates the log is full when in fact it's the hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the log was being filled from a previous statement - one that modifies a column on a large table. Adding the foreign key constraint was just the straw that broke the camel's back.